# Sentry Auto-init does not work because it is disabled in the library being used

Tags: android, android-manifest, sentry, manifest-merging

I use [Sentry configuration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/manual-setup/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) via AndroidManifest.xml.
In the manifest I have these lines:

```
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.dsn" android:value="my_value" />
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.traces.user-interaction.enable" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.traces.sample-rate" android:value="1.0" />
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.traces.profiling.sample-rate" android:value="1.0" />
```

But Sentry console is empty and i see this in logcat:

```
io.sentry.auto-init read: false
```

I also check used libs and found that one of them has this line in the own manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.sentry.auto-init" android:value="false" />
```

So I tried to add this line to my manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.sentry.auto-init" android:value="false" tools:replace="android:value"/>
```

And it looks like sentry is now working, but is this the right decision? What could be the consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't recommend using sentry in SDKs/libraries due to the following reasons:

[image]

Which library is doing that exactly? You should approach them and let them know that they shouldn't call `SentryAndroid.init` or `Sentry.init` as a library, because it will conflict with the hosting application.

Comment: This is our company library. They do not initialize Sentry in the library, and they also disabled automatic initialization, most likely for the reasons you gave. So I enabled automatic initialization in the manifest of our application (not the library), but I wanted to know if I did the right thing

Comment: so the library does not itself initialize Sentry? Then I think it should be fine, if you're enabling auto-init in the hosting application, I don't see any issues with that. Just make sure you initialize sentry only once (either via auto-init or manually, doesn't matter) and that no other library initializes it.